# Create a tree list/table in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, tree, apache-poi

How can I create a tree list/table in Excel using Apache POI? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation nor on google/so.

[image: Example how it should look like]

Comment: What's wrong with [Sheet.groupRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#groupRow(int,%20int)) and [Sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRowGroupCollapsed(int,%20boolean)) ?

Comment: @Gagravarr actually you're right, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key methods you need to use are:

- [Sheet.groupRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#groupRow(int,%20int))
- [Sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRowGroupCollapsed(int,%20boolean))

There are two Apache POI examples that cover row grouping and outlining, which you'd be well advised to review:

- [Outlining](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/Outlining.java)
- [BusinessPlan](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/BusinessPlan.java)